# how can I merge two structs and print values of both in uitableviewcell in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Below are my two structs, and I want to print values from both structs in UITableViewCell

```
struct MainCell: Decodable
{
    let job_id: String
    let job_desig: String
    let job_desc: String
    let job_location: String
    let job_emp_gender: String
    let job_skills: String
    let company_id: Int

}
struct Company: Decodable{
    let company_id: Int
    let company_name: String
}

var mainCellData = [MainCell]()
var companyData = [Company]()
```

**- TableView Methods**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return mainCellData.count + companyData.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:JobDetails_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell") as! JobDetails_TableViewCell

        for jobs in mainCellData {
            cell.lblDesig.text = jobs.job_desig
            cell.lblDesc.text = jobs.job_desc
            cell.lblLocation.text = jobs.job_location
            cell.comName.text = jobs.name.company_name
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**As I want to print job_desig, job_desc and job_location from my first struct (struct MainCell: Decodable) and company_name from my second struct (struct Company: Decodable)**

Can anybody help me with my issue?

Comment: is your mainCellData contains only one object of MainCell?

Comment: @PPL no it contains the whole struct (from-job_id to-company_id)

Comment: What you actually want to do? do you want to display two cells? first for MainCell and second for Company?

Comment: The whole struct means one object of struct, am I right?

Comment: @PPL No I want to display the whole bunch of information in single cell only

Comment: Please check my answer hope it is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't match your requirement.
2. Get rid of the `for` loop in `cellForRowAt`.
3. You don't need to merge anything. You need to look up the company name based on its id.

Your code should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainCellData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:JobDetails_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell") as! JobDetails_TableViewCell

    let data = mainCellData[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblDesig.text = data.job_desig
    cell.lblDesc.text = data.job_desc
    cell.lblLocation.text = data.job_location
    cell.comName.text = companyData.first { $0.company_id == data.company_id }?.company_name

    return cell
}
```

The real trick is getting the company name. The idea is that you have `data.company_id` which is of course the company_id for the row being displayed. You need to iterate through the `companyData` array and find a `Company` that has the same `company_id`. When a match is found, get the `company_name` from that matching company.

The code `companyData.first { $0.company_id == data.company_id }?.company_name` means:

Iterate through the `companyData` array and find the first entry where the company_id equals `data.company_id`. If a match is found, return its `company_name`.

Comment: companyData.filter not companyData.first

Comment: @Sh_Khan, no, I mean `first`, not `filter`. The idea is to get the first matching company based on id.

Comment: may be  ids are not sorted

Comment: @Sh_Khan They don't need to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add count for numberOfRow, 
It is not good practice to manage two array for tableview you should combine in one struct like below 
You can create one struct to maintain your all datasource

```
struct MainStruct {

    var mainCellData :MainCell
    var companyData :Company?

}
```

**EDIT**

and fill your data source like this in viewDidLoad or whenever you got your array

```
var data = [MainStruct]()
for object in mainCellData {
   let obj = companyData.first{$0.company_id == object.company_id }
    data.append(MainStruct(mainCellData: object, companyData: obj))
}
```

Now

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:JobDetails_TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell") as! JobDetails_TableViewCell

    let data = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblDesig.text = data.mainCellData.job_desig
    cell.lblDesc.text = data.mainCellData.job_desc
    cell.lblLocation.text = data.mainCellData.job_location
    cell.comName.text = data.companyData?.company_name

    return cell
}
```

Hope it is helpful